# What is the purpose of duplicating commands in a Powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, command

I have inherited a bunch of powershell scripts from a developer who has very suddenly left our company. Whilst I am able to follow the logic of the scripts, many of the commands are duplicated, like so:

```
"cd " + $targetDirectory
cd $targetDirectory

"hg pull"
& hg pull

"hg revert --all"
& hg revert --all

"hg up default"
& hg up default
```

The first always containing quotation marks, and second having some sort of powershell syntax.

What is the purpose of duplicating commands like so, ie, what does it achieve?

Comment: Without "duplicating" each line you can achieve the same result (listing commands before they execute) by using `Set-PSDebug -trace 1`

Comment: Something you might find useful in understanding how these scripts work, is to use the Powershell Integrated Script Environment (ISE) and set a breakpoint (F9 key) on the first line of a script and then step through the script a line at a time (F10) and observe what happens with each line. In the case of the script in the OP you will see that the first line in each pair outputs to the console and the second line executes the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly poor practice I think. Essentially, this is just making a string that contains the command being run, and sending it to the output stream, where you probably see it in the console. Then it executes the actual command.

It's like having to manually echo everything. The strings, if they must be sent to the console, should be sent with `Write-Host` or (in my opinion) `Write-Verbose` so that they aren't part of the output stream anymore.

In your own script you can use `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` (thanks [Χpẘ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2460798/%CE%A7p%E1%BA%98)).

In newer versions of powershell especially, there are ways to log every command run in any powershell session (even if you have no access to the code being run) to the event log. I'm having trouble finding a good article to link to at the moment, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: This last advice make much sense, that makes it a bad practice, indeed

Comment: `Set-PSDebug -trace 1` will trace each line. It has been around since at least PS 2.0

Answer (score 2):

It's only meant to output in the console the command being run, just before it's being run, almost like debug messages.